# Confirmation message and warning message to set

Tags: perl

i want to add functionality ask for confirmation before adding entry into database and also want to check if that iteration exist in database then it should throw warning message. my code is :

## Really create iterations

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:mysql:dbname=agilefant-test",
    "agilefant-test",
    "Agilefant-test",
    { RaiseError => 1 },
) or die $DBI::errstr;

foreach $iter (keys(%iterations)) {
        my $req = "INSERT into backlogs (backlogtype, name, startDate, endDate, parent_id) VALUES ('Iteration', '$iter', '" .
                                $iterations{ $iter }->{start} . " 08:00', '" .
                                $iterations{ $iter }->{end} . " 18:00', '" .
                                $project . "');" ;
        print $req . "\n";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT into backlogs (backlogtype, name, startDate, endDate, parent_id) VALUES ('Iteration', '$iter', '" .
                                $iterations{ $iter }->{start} . " 08:00', '" .
                                $iterations{ $iter }->{end} . " 18:00', '" .
                                $project . "');");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->finish();

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you come up with a better question title than `Hi, I want to ask`?

Comment: You don't need to include language in the question title.  Use tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly.

Ask for confirmation: i'd do something like

```
print "insert iteration $iter?";
$yesno=<>;
if (substr($yesno, 0, 1) eq "y") {
    .... handle the insert
}
```

As to warning message: Do something like

```
$stmt="select count(1) from backlogs where name='$iter'";
$sth=$dbh->prepare($stmt);
$sth->execute();
($count)=$sth->fetchrow_array();
if ($count>0) {
    print "WARNING: $iter already exists.\n";
}
```

Of course, this can be made more efficient if you use bound variables (and prevents sql injection as well in cases where you can't truse the source of $iter):

```
# this goes in front of the loop
$stmt="select count(1) from backlogs where name=?";
$sth=$dbh->prepare($stmt);

# this goes inside the loop
$sth->execute($iter);
($count)=$sth->fetchrow_array();
if ($count>0) {
    print "WARNING: $iter already exists.\n";
}
```

If you have a unique index on the name column, you can also just execute the insert statement, then check for oracle error ORA-23000 which means you just tried to insert a second row.

Comment: Oops, just noticed you're using mysql. In that case, ORA-23000 becomes mysql error code 2525.

Comment: thansk but when i tried for warning message i am getting:DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_array failed: fetch() without execute() at ./create_iteration.pl line 99.
DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_array failed: fetch() without execute() at ./create_iteration.pl line 99.

Comment: When i use Confirmation it ask to add iterations or not for only 1,3,4,5 iterations not 2. :( and giving error Use of uninitialized value in substr at

Comment: Sorry, but i can't answer that as i don't know the rest of your program. A fetch, used directly after an execute, certainly shouldn't give a fetch without execute warning unless you're mixing up some variables.